# How to identify a page break is within a paragraph using interop c#

Tags: c#, interop, document, page-break

I have a paragraph which has a page break in between the paragraph i.e the paragraph is continuing next page (widow paragraph) now i want to identify is there any page break is presented in between the paragraph using interop c#.But some times paragraph is ending at the end of the page , i can see page break but pilcrow symbol (paragraph mark(¶)) is alone placing at the starting of the next page.

Comment: What type of documents You're reading ? After reading Your code I assume it's a .cs file, but I think You meant something else like MS Word or sth.

Comment: its a doc file(.doc) @MajkeloDev